# If $p \in \alpha$, $q \in Q$, and $q < p$, then $q \in \alpha$: Proving Two Implications. Principles of Mathematical Analysis By Walter Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I am told that the following proposition (II) is true by definition. I then attempt to prove the two implications that follow from (II) being true.

> The members of $R$ will be certain subsets of $Q$, called cuts. A cut is, by definition, any set $\alpha \subset Q$ with the following three properties.
>
> (I) ...
>
> (II) If $p \in \alpha$, $q \in Q$, and $q < p$, then $q \in \alpha$.
>
> (III) ...
>
> The letters $p, q, r, ...$ denote rational numbers, and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, ...$ will denote cuts.
>
> (II) implies ...
>
> If $p \in \alpha$ and $q \not\in \alpha$, then $p < q$.
>
> If $r \not\in \alpha$ and $r < s$, then $s \not\in \alpha$.

Proof of Theorem 1.19, Step 1, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* By Walter Rudin.

---

**First Proof**

Let $p \in \alpha$ and $q \not\in \alpha$.

$\alpha = \{ p,q \in Q : q < p \}$ *From (II).*

$q \not\in \alpha \rightarrow q \in \{ p,q \in Q : q > p \}$ *Since an object is a member of a set if and only if it satisfies the defining property of the set.*

$Q.E.D.$

**Second Proof**

Let $r \not\in \alpha$ and $r < s$.

$\alpha = \{ p,q \in Q : q < p \}$ *From (II).*

Since we had $r \not\in \alpha$ in the hypothesis, we can say that there is no $q \in Q$ such that $q < r$.

Therefore, $q > r \ \forall q \in Q, r \not\in \alpha$

Let $s = q$.

Since we have $r \not\in \alpha$, $s \in \{ s, r \in Q : s > r \}$

Therefore, we can conclude that $s \not\in \alpha = \{ s, r \in Q : s < r \}$

$Q.E.D.$

---

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my proofs for correctness.

---

**New Second Proof**

Let $r \not\in \alpha$ and $r < s$.

$\{ q \in Q : q < p \} \subseteq \alpha$ *This is from (II).*

$r \not\in \alpha \rightarrow r \not\in \{ q \in Q : q < p \} \subseteq \alpha$

$r \in \{ q \in Q : q > p \}$ *Since if $q = p$, then $q = r \in \alpha$.*

Since we have that $r < s$, $r \in \{ q \in Q : s > q > p \}$

But how can I conclude from here that $s \not\in \alpha$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in both cases, you should note that your definition of cut $\alpha$ is not proper since:
$$\alpha=\{p,q\in \mathbb{Q}:q<p\}$$
is not clear enough. By that, I mean that, when describing a set, at left you note the elements of this set of which "greater" set are elements, hence, when you say that $\alpha$ consists of $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$, it is not clear whether you intend that both $p,q$ belong to $\alpha$ or not. It would be more proper to mention that:
$$\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q<p\}\subseteq\alpha\tag{rule}$$

Now, we can use the following rule from mathematical logic:
$$(A\Rightarrow B)\Leftrightarrow(\neg B\Rightarrow\neg A)$$
Now, for your first proof, let $p\in\alpha$ and $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. We know that:
$$q<p\Rightarrow q\in\alpha$$
From our rule, we have that:
$$(q<p\Rightarrow q\in\alpha)\Leftrightarrow(q\not\in\alpha\Rightarrow q\geq p)$$
Now, since $p\in\alpha$ and $q\not\in\alpha$, it is clear that $p\neq q$, so, we have that $q>p$.

Can you, now, use these thoughts and your own ideas to alter you second proof?

**Edit:** As far as why $\alpha_p:=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q<p\}\subseteq\alpha$ and not neccessarily $\alpha_p=\alpha$, it is not guaranteed by property $(II)$ that $\alpha$ even represents a rational number, so no-one can ensure us that $p$ is the $\max\alpha$ or the $\sup\alpha$. So, there might exist $s>p$ such that $s\in\alpha$, which means that $\alpha_p\subset\alpha$.

**Further edit:** As for the second proof, note at first that, for two sets $A,B$ if $A\subseteq B$ does not mean that $B\subseteq A^c$, where with $A^c$ we note the complementary set of $A$. So, it is not true that:
$$\alpha\subset\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q\geq p\}$$
Moreover, as for $s$, it cannot belong in the set $\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:s>q>p\}$ (can you see why?). Try to mimic the proof of the first claim using the first claim and the rule described.

As a further explanation to the rule, what it is stated is that, you can say that "if $A$ is true, then $B$ is true" if and only if you can say that "if $B$ is not true, then $A$ is not true".

Comment: Thanks for the response. Before I rewrite the second proof, can you please elaborate on why we have $\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q<p\}\subseteq\alpha$ instead of $\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q<p\} = \alpha$? Wouldn't the latter be more accurate?

Comment: I' ve added some clarification over that, in a new edit.

Comment: This makes sense to me now. Thank you. I will begin trying to redo the second proof.

Comment: Nice! Also note that $\alpha_p$ as defined in this case is exactly the cut that defines the rational number $p$.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean it is exactly the cut that defines the rational number $p$? I'm not sure what is meant by this.

Comment: Every real number is defined as a Dedekind cut - the cuts mentioned in your question. Actually, they are defined as pairs of such cuts. So, the set $\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q<p\}$ is exactly all these rational numbers that are "before" $p$. In general, the notion of "cut" is that we define the real numbers as the rational numbers + the "gaps" between them. So, every real number, in a way, "cuts" the rational numbers into two "cuts", as defined in your question.

Comment: But does this not only define the rational numbers $< p$? How does it define the rational $p$ itself?

Comment: Also, I have edited my main post with the new second proof.

Comment: Every real number is defined as a set, not as a number. So, every cut defines a number. More specifically, every real number is defined as the set of all the rational numbers than are lesser than the number itself.

Comment: I have made another edit.

Comment: Well, you can prove it by contradiction. Suppose $s\in\alpha$ and, taking into account that $r<s$ you can make use of property $(II)$. But, now, you also see that the previous steps where not needed. In general, in this "primitive" stage of calculus, probably the most valuable tool you have is proving by contradiction and/or using logical "tricks" as the one mentioned in the first proof (this second proof can be done in both ways).

Comment: Ahh, I think I found one. So we have that $r \not\in \alpha$ and $r < s$. We also have $s \in \alpha$, as you said. (II) Says that, if $p \in \alpha$, $q \in Q$, and $q < p$, then $q \in \alpha$. So we have that $s \in \alpha$, $r \in Q$, and $r < s$. Therefore, by (II), we can conclude that $r \in \alpha$. But this is a contradiction! Does this proof look correct?

Comment: Yeap! That's allright! :) Can you, now also prove it - just for excercise reasons; your proof is correct and nicely short - without using, in any manner, contradiction?

Comment: Ok, I think I have it. I continue from $r \in \{ q \in Q : s > q > p \}$, as stated in the edit in my main post. We have that the proposition (II) is equivalent to its contrapositive: $(A \rightarrow B) \iff (NOT B \rightarrow NOT A)$. But $(NOT B \rightarrow NOT A)$ is equivalent to the inverse of (II) (according to logic tables): $(A \rightarrow B) \iff (NOT A \rightarrow NOT B)$. We can now assume that $(NOT A \rightarrow NOT B)$ is true in our proof: If $p \in \alpha$ and $q > p$, then $q \not\in \alpha$.

Comment: We had that $r \in \{ q \in Q : s > q > p \}$. Since $p \in \alpha$ and $s > p$, then $s \not\in \alpha$. Does this seem correct? The main idea is using logic (inverse), based on equivalences?

Comment: I used this logic table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD39T.png

Comment: Again, $p\in\alpha$ and $s>p$ would imply $s\not\in\alpha$ if and only if $\alpha=\alpha_p$, For instance, if we define $\alpha=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q^2<2\text{ or }q<0\}$, then, for whichever $p\in\alpha$ you may choose, you can always find $s>p$ such that $x\in\alpha$. However, it is true that using the contrapositive of property (II) you can prove the second corrollary. For instance; let $r<s$ and then try to play with the clause $r\not\in\alpha\Rightarrow s\not\in\alpha$.

Comment: Ok, this is similar to my last failed attempt. The inverse of (II) (NOT A $\rightarrow$ NOT B) is, "If $p \in \alpha$, $q \in Q$, and $q > p$, then $q \not\in \alpha$". This is equivalent to (II). The contrapositive of (II) is, "If $p \in \alpha$, $q \in Q$, and $q \not\in \alpha$, then $q > p$. This is equivalent to (II). $\therefore r \in \{ q \in Q : q > p \}$. Since $r \in \{ q \in Q : q > p \}$ and $s > r$, we can say that $r \in \{ q \in Q : s > q > p \}$. $\therefore s > p$. And by the inverse of (II), we can conclude that $s \not\in \alpha$, since $p \in \alpha$, $s \in Q$, and $s > p$

Comment: This is almost correct. I say "almost" due to the fact that, when negating a clause of the form $A\land B\land C$, where $\land$ is the logical "and", its negation is $\neg A\lor\neg B\lor\neg C$, where $\lor$ is the logical "or" and $\neg$ is the logical negation - de Morgan's law, is how this is called, check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws. Then, the whole proccedure is made a little more difficult since a clause of the form $P\lor Q$ is true if just on of $P$ or $Q$ is true, you you have to consider several specific cases. Instead, you could take $A,B$ as granted...

Comment: ...and prove that $C\Rightarrow D$ using its contrapositive.

Comment: Ok, here we go again. We first take the contrapositive of (II), using the case where $p \in \alpha$ and $q \in Q$ remain the same, but we negate $q < p$ to $q > p$. So we have (NOT B $\rightarrow$ NOT A) $\implies$ ($q \not\in \alpha \rightarrow p \in \alpha \land q \in Q \land q > p$). $\therefore r \in \{ q \in Q : q > p \}$. We have that $r < s$, so we now have that $r \in \{ q \in Q : s > q > p \}$. The inverse of (II) is (NOT A $\rightarrow$ NOT B). We will assume the case where $p \in \alpha, q \in Q, $ and $q > p$. ...

Comment: Therefore, (NOT A $\rightarrow$ NOT B) $\implies$ ($p \in \alpha \land q \in Q \land q > p \rightarrow q \not\in \alpha$). Therefore, $s \not\in \alpha$, since $s > p, s \in Q$, and $p \in \alpha.$ $Q.E.D.$

Comment: Your thought is correct, just avoid including $A\land B\land C$ in your $\rightarrow$. You could, instead, say: given $r<s$ we will prove that $r\not\in\alpha\Rightarrow s\not\in\alpha$. From its contrapositive, we have that this is equivalent to $s\in\alpha\Rightarrow r\in\alpha$ which is true from (II), since it has been assumed that $r<s$.

Comment: I see. So this would be a succinct version of the proof? But my longer version would also be correct, right? (Just to make sure I haven't made any errors.)

Comment: In general yes, you only "lose points" from the fact that you keep $A\land B\land C$ in your contrapositive clause as well, so it is better, and simpler to first assume these two seperately and then play with a simpler clause.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. We have that $(r \not\in \alpha \land r < s) \rightarrow s \not\in \alpha$. Let $A = r \not\in \alpha, B = r < s, C = s \not\in \alpha$. So we have $(A \land B) \rightarrow C$. The contrapositive of this would be $\neg (A \land B) \rightarrow \neg C$, which would be $\neg C \rightarrow (\neg A \lor \neg B)$. If we assume $B$ and instead have $\neg A$, the contrapositive becomes $(B \land \neg C) \rightarrow \neg A$, which is the same as $(r < s \land s \in \alpha) \rightarrow r \in \alpha$. You then use (II) to show that $s \in \alpha$.

Comment: Yeap. It is like saying that if $A$ and $B$ imply $C$, then, it is like $A$ implies the implication $B\Rightarrow C$. So $$(A\land B\Rightarrow C)\leftrightarrow(A\Rightarrow(B\Rightarrow C))$$

Comment: This has been very educational. Thank you very much for all of your assistance!

Comment: You' re wellcome! That why Math.SE exists! :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\alpha$ is not given explicitly as a set, it's given that it's a set with specific properties. Your approach to describe $\alpha$ as a set using $p, q$ is wrong. The implications can be proved easily using contradiction (assume hypotheses and negative of conclusion).

Thus to prove the first implication assume that $p\in\alpha, q\notin\alpha$ (hypotheses) as well as $q\leq p$ (negative of the conclusion). Now if $q=p$ then $q\in\alpha$ because $p\in\alpha$. And if $q<p$ then by the property (II) $q\in\alpha$. This is the contradiction which proves the implication. You can try to prove the other implication as well in a similar manner.

Moreover you should try to go beyond the symbols and think about their meaning in your natural language. Thus if $p\in\alpha$ then by second property we see that all numbers smaller than $p$ are also in $\alpha$. So whatever is not lying in $\alpha$ must necessarily be greater than $p$.

---

You may ask why we can't describe the set $\alpha$ in the manner you are trying. Well, the properties of $\alpha$ are meant to describe a general cut and not any specific chosen cut. All the cuts satisfy those properties and using those properties alone you can't describe a specific cut.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ahh, I see. But we can do as @Βασίλης Μάρκος did and describe our set as a subset of $\alpha$? This makes sense to me.

Comment: @ThePointer : yes but then you are only describing subsets of $\alpha$ and this does not characterize $\alpha$. But if that approach helps in understanding you should definitely go for it. Also try to think of these in your natural language. You will find them very trivial. The symbolism makes such trivialities very hard to understand.